# Tag Manager not firing on AMP pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html

I'm using Google Tag Manager with an AMP container. I integrated it with a simple Google Analytics tag [image]

Here the code used in the head:

```
<!-- AMP Analytics --><script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
```

and in the body:

```
<amp-analytics config="https://www.googletagmanager.com/amp.json?id=GTM-NVKMFDF&gtm.url=SOURCE_URL" data-credentials="include">
    <script type="application/json">
        ...
    </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

But Analytics is not receiving any hits from AMP pages.
I tried also removing the `<script>` inside the `<amp-analytics>` tag, but nothing changed.

You can see the implementation here: https://www.tomshw.it/migliori-libri-matematica?view=amp

While, if I integrate the code of [Google Analytics for AMP pages](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/), it works. However, I would like to use GTM.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, based from this [blog](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2016/10/google-tag-manager-giving-mobile.html), Tag Manager is now supported in AMP which provides support across Google’s ad platforms including AdWords and DoubleClick. You can check the support page for a full list of [supported tags](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106924) and information on how to use [built-in variables](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/topic/7182737).

**Tag Manager not firing on AMP pages**

You can check [here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103683?hl=en) the possible causes for tag firing problems:

- Unpublished changes
- Wrong trigger configuration
- Triggers too specific
- Unexpected site or app changes
- Too many HTTP requests
- Container snippet problems

Here's a [tutorial](https://www.advancedwebranking.com/blog/how-to-use-googles-tag-manager-on-accelerated-mobile-pages/) about *How to Use Google’s Tag Manager on Accelerated Mobile Pages* which might help.

Answer (score 1):

The AMP JS libraries (https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js in your case)  should come at last just before closing of head tag. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but I just ran into this and there's no other info out there I could find!

It looks like AMP pages don't support the debug window you expect here.

[Google Tag Manager, AMP Container preview mode, doesnt work through amp-analytics #19883](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/19883)

> "AMP containers in Google Tag Manager (GTM) do not support the debug
>   window you are referring to. Preview mode will still let you preview
>   your changes prior to publishing."

[Some other information - accelerated-mobile-pages-via-google-tag-manager](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/accelerated-mobile-pages-via-google-tag-manager/):

> Google Tag Manager for AMP does not support the Debug mode we’re used
>   to with regular Google Tag Manager. The debug panel would require that
>   the AMP page supported the type of JavaScript that is very
>   performance-killing.
>
> However, GTM does work in Preview Mode. So when you enter Preview Mode
>   in Google Tag Manager, once you reload the site with the same web
>   browser you entered Preview Mode in, the container that is downloaded
>   from Google Tag Manager will actually be the one you are previewing
>   and not the one that is published.
>
> This is very useful, even though I know you’ll miss having the
>   excellent Debug panel at your disposal.
>
> Because Preview Mode doesn’t have any verbose logging or anything like
>   that, you should get familiar with other debug tools at your disposal.